# bootstrap datetimepicker get day

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am a newbie in here.

```js
   $("#tanggal_arsip").datetimepicker({
   var day = daysofweek.value,
   format:"yyyy-mm-dd"
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="tanggal_arsip" id="tanggal_arsip" data-format="YYYY-MM-DD" placeholder="Tanggal Berita" required />
```

I have a question about datetimpicker.
How to get name of days in bootstrap datetimepicker?
For example i want to get Sunday or other day or just a number for day.

I can't find this problem in bootstrap datetimepicker documentation.

Comment: The description of your problem is unclear. The name of days already shows in the date/time picker, doesn't it? In the popup.

Answer (score 1):

First: your input tag is wrong. You can see how to use it in the snippet.

You can use the following event:

> [dp.change](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange): Fired when the date is changed.
>
> parameters:
>
> e = {
>
> ```
> date, //date the picker changed to. Type: moment object (clone)
> oldDate //previous date. Type: moment object (clone) or false in the event of a null
> ```
>
> }

Using the **date** parameter contained in the event object and the moment methods [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) you can write (in the snippet you can see a different approach: select a day and show only the day of week):

```js
$('#tanggal_arsip').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
}).on('dp.change', function(e) {
    //
    // on date change get current date and format as weekday
    //
    $('#weekDay').val(e.date.format('dddd'));
});

//
// select by day and show only day of week
//

$('#tanggal_arsip1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dddd',
    viewMode: 'days'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <label class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 control-label">Date:</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group date" id="tanggal_arsip">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 control-label">Day of Week:</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <input id="weekDay" type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <label class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 control-label">Select by day and Show Only Day Of Week:</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group date" id="tanggal_arsip1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just parse the result of $("datetime selector").val() to get the day and convert that to a word name if you need it.